# signalR and SQL backplane send message to group

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr, signalr-backplane

I have the an issue with Groups, sending message to groups via SQL back plane

I followed the steps outlined  [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-sql-server) , With out a back plane configured my client recives all messages via group, when i configure a back plane my client does not recived message.

I have put debug printing on `OnDisconnected(),  OnReconnected()` and they are not fired. so i know the client is still connected

Comment: When are you adding your clients to their groups. Are you awaiting the call to Groups.Add?

Comment: I'm adding the client to the groups after the OnConnected event is triggered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I was saving the `IHubContext` instance , I changed it so on every use I will take a fresh copy if the `IHubContext` like this :

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHubName>()
```